# i want a program that compares 100 numbers in the memory with FFH and print something

Tags: assembly

```
org 100h


mov cx,100
mov si,0

s1:
mov ax,[si]

cmp ax,100H

je s2

inc si
jmp s1

s2:

print'above' ;emulator gives me wrong parameter here!!!!!!!!!

inc si

jmp s1

END
```

Comment: You *want* a program? But you already have one.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to include a question at all!

Comment: read the program plz there is a comment after print instruction

Comment: You haven't provided any information about what `print` is or how it works.

Comment: i used emu8086 program

Answer (score 1):

If the following line gives you trouble ...

```
print'above' ;emulator gives me wrong parameter here!!!!!!!!!
```

... then you could just use another way to output the text 'above'.

```
s2:
mov dx, msg
mov ah, 9
int 21h
```

and have somewhere else in your program

```
msg  db  'above','$'
```

Note that to compare with FFh and display 'above' you should write

```
...
s1:
mov ax,[si]
cmp ax,0FFH
ja s2
...
```

The program you've written so far will run forever because you don't do anything useful with that counter in CX.